# Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8888 refused in intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, gradle

I added to my gradle.build 2 dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2'
```

I try to refresh from Intellij and I get an error:

[image]

[image]
I try to build from cmd
and I get this error:

```
>Could not resolve com.google.http-client:google-http-client:.
  Required by:
      :RoutingRegression:1.0
   > Could not GET 'http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository/com/google/http-client/google-http-client//google-http-client-.pom'.
      > Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8888 refused
> Could not resolve com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:.
  Required by:
      :RoutingRegression:1.0
   > Could not GET 'http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-jackson2//google-http-client-jackson2-.pom'.
      > Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8888 refused

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: What repositories do you have configured?

Comment: Please show the `repositories{}` section of your build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

It seems some other application in you machine is using the port 8888, can you try closing the application and try build again